# gradle.buildStarted not triggered

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am not able to have buildStarted triggered in my gradle build, not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have a root project gradle file like this 
version '1.0'

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/gradle-plugins' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.1.0')
    }
}

gradle.buildStarted {
    println "buildStart"
}

gradle. buildFinished {
    println "buildFinished"
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'
.........
```

`buildFinished` works as I am able to see corresponding println but `buildStarted` never seem to get triggered.

**EDIT**
Include init.gradle that uses build listener

```
class MyBuildAdapter extends BuildAdapter {
    void buildStarted(Gradle gradle) {
       println "buildStarted"
    }    
}

gradle.addBuildListener new MyBuildAdapter()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `buildStarted` event occurs before you get a chance to register a callback in a build script. You'll have to use one of the other hooks. For details, see [Gradle.addBuildListener](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html#addBuildListener%28org.gradle.BuildListener%29) in the Javadoc.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in my post, I tried doing that as well but it did not work. I am updating the post with the code snippet.

Comment: Again, the problem is that the buildStarted event occurs before you get a chance to register a callback in a build script. **You'll have to use one of the other hooks**.

Comment: Okay. I am trying to download gradle.properties for a project before the build gets started. Without gradle.properties none of the property placeholders in build script will be substituted. So far the buildListener triggers `projectEvaluated` & `taskGraph.whenReady` but these stages are too late in the build lifecycle to not have gradle.properties. Is it possible to do anything like this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, as `gradle.properties` is read very early on. It should be committed to source control. I'd only configure things like Gradle memory settings there, and would move user-defined properties into a build script or script plugin.

Comment: Hello! How can I get total build time?

Total time: 1.721 secs

Can i access it somehow from BuildResult in void buildFinished(BuildResult result)? @PeterNiederwieser

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a custom plugin I wrote, and found that only `projectsEvaluated` callback is the one that gets executed before `buildFinished` in the `BuildListener`.

It's been 7 years, and finally Gradle got around to admitting that it didn't make sense to have this method in the first place. It'll be removed in Gradle 7.

https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#apis_buildlistener_buildstarted_and_gradle_buildstarted_have_been_deprecated